# How to generate full backups of a DB with independent backup chains?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I've trying to generate independent full backups of a DB and I can't get the result I'm looking for. For what I read, a full database backup will create a new backup chain and the succesive differential backups performed are 'chained' to that full backup. However, when I running the script for backup the database two times, the result is that the second full backup depends of the first one.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Pruebas2] TO  DISK = 'C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2.bak' WITH NOINIT, NAME = N'Database Backup',STATS = 10;
BACKUP DATABASE [Pruebas2] TO  DISK = 'C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL,NOINIT, NAME = N'Database Backup',STATS = 10;

--new backup of DB ' Pruebas2' saved into a different file
BACKUP DATABASE [Pruebas2] TO  DISK = 'C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2_2.bak' WITH NOINIT, NAME = N'Database Backup',STATS = 10;
BACKUP DATABASE [Pruebas2] TO  DISK = 'C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2_2.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL,NOINIT, NAME = N'Database Backup',STATS = 10;
```

These are the results of queryng msdb.dbo.backupset:

```
physical_device_name                position    type    backup_start_date       backup_finish_date      first_lsn           checkpoint_lsn      database_backup_lsn

C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2.bak     1           D       2019-05-16 15:15:14.000 2019-05-16 15:15:14.000 32000000034300102   32000000034300102   0

C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2.bak     2           I       2019-05-16 15:15:14.000 2019-05-16 15:15:14.000 32000000039600034   32000000039600034   32000000034300102

C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2_2.bak   1           D       2019-05-16 15:15:59.000 2019-05-16 15:15:59.000 32000000041400037   32000000041400037   32000000034300102

C:\temp\new\Backup_pruebas2_2.bak   3           I       2019-05-16 15:33:16.000 2019-05-16 15:33:16.000 32000000043900034   32000000043900034   32000000041400037
```

I would expect that 'database_backup_lsn' was 0 for the full backup  stored in "Backup_pruebas2_2.bak" file instead of 32000000034300102, which is linked with the first full backup

What script will create a new(independent) backup chain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is correct.

Database_backup_lsn is defined as
"Log sequence number of the most recent full database backup. Can be NULL.
Database_backup_lsn is the "begin of checkpoint" that is triggered when the backup starts. This LSN will coincide with first_lsn if the backup is taken when the database is idle and no replication is configured."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

So the second backups only keeps pointer to previous one, but there is no dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond Piotr! So, can I make a RESTORE using only  the second file which contains the second full backup?

Comment: Yes. As usual always test your backups and any answers from internet ;)

Comment: Thanks! I just try the RECOVER operation only using the second full backup (and removing the first backup full file) and everything was OK!